# How to config jrebel in Hybris backoffice extensions?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel

After I created one backoffice extension using "ant extgen with ybackoffice template".
And I want add jrebel to this backoffice extensions but not reloading when i change code. 
So, please help me to solve the problem to save time for deployment.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check if backoffice extensions packaged as .jar packages contain `rebel.xml` files and if you make a code change in `.java` file, new `.class` files are generated in `$PLATFORM_HOME/bin/custom/$EXTENSION_NAME/backoffice/classes` directory that is defined in `rebel.xml`.

*copy-paste from [documentation](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/standalone/hybris.html#configuration) portal:*

**Backoffice extensions** that are packaged as JAR files need a descriptor file called `rebel.xml`. This XML file will tell JRebel that the `.class` files for this JAR are in that folder. To achieve this, you will need to do the following for all extensions you want reloaded:

To recompile via an IDE, set the compile output to where the classes are actually compiled to with ant build. For backoffice extensions, this would be `$PLATFORM_HOME/bin/custom/$EXTENSION_NAME/backoffice/classes`.

Create the following `rebel.xml` in `$EXTENSION_NAME/backoffice/resources`:

```
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://update.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/rebel-2_1.xsd">
  <classpath>
    <!-- Make sure to replace $PLATFORM_HOME and $EXTENSION_NAME with your concrete values -->
    <dir name="$PLATFORM_HOME/bin/custom/$EXTENSION_NAME/backoffice/classes"/>
  </classpath>
</application>
```

Edit `$EXTENSION_NAME/buildcallbacks.xml` and add the following before build callback:

```
<macrodef name="$EXTENSION_NAME_before_build">
  <sequential>
    <mkdir dir="${ext.$EXTENSION_NAME.path}/backoffice/classes" />
      <copy file="${ext.$EXTENSION_NAME.path}/backoffice/resources/rebel.xml" todir="${ext.$EXTENSION_NAME.path}/backoffice/classes/" failonerror="false" />
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

This will make sure that rebel.xml is bundled into the compiled extension JAR file on build.

When changing classes from the IDE, just recompile the class (either with ant build or via the IDE after setting the correct compile output) and reload the browser. The changed .class files are picked up by JRebel and reloaded on the fly.